# Partial Page Rendering in Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a way for partial page rendering in Spring MVC 3?
I am looking forsomething similar to PPR in apache trinidad.
http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/ppr.html

Comment: Have you looked at Thymeleaf fragments?

Comment: @chrylis I tried to use thymeleaf and followed the steps in this [link] (http://xpadro.blogspot.in/2014/02/thymeleaf-integration-with-spring-part-2.html) but I am not able to render the div .I have asked another question in this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993932/ajax-in-springthymeleaf)